# How to exclude inherited tags from the parent POM?

Tags: maven

[My POM will inherit everything from the parent POM](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-project-relationships.html), including contents which are irrelevant for my project: `mailingLists`, `issueManagement`, `ciManagement` and so on.

I'm aware I could overwrite them, or simply ignore them, so that they appear in the effective POM of my project. But is there any way to simply exclude them from my child POM?

A workaround would be to provide those tags with blank content, or some dummy content to skip the links from the parent. But this solution does not seem elegant at all...
Moreover, *grandchildren* POMs would automatically append the `${artifactId}` at the end of each blank or dummy attribute, making things even worse.

Comment: You are inheriting them so you can't exclude them like in Java you inherit the methods/attributes but you can't exclude them. Furthermore where is the `${artifactId}` appended? Can you give a real example of your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no standard Maven way to influence this order in the final pom (assumptation based on the fact the official documentation does not describe anything regarding the order of elements in the resulting final pom output but only the order of definition of certain key parts such as dependencies and the relating effect of "which one wins over the definition of the other based on who was configured first/last").

Note that regarding plugins a common pattern is to have plugins defined in the `pluginManagament` section of a common parent pom.xml allowing childs to include only specificly defined plugins rather than  implicitly inheriting all parent plugins.

After a few tests messing around with `dependencyManagement` and `profiles` I dont think there is a workaround using Maven standards.